# Call parent method from child class c#

Tags: c#, .net

This is a slightly different question from previous answers I have seen or I am not getting it. I have a parent class with a method named `MyMethod()` and a variable `public Int32 CurrentRow;`

```
public void MyMethod()
{    
     this.UpdateProgressBar();    
}
```

In the parent I create a new instance of `ChildClass`

```
Boolean loadData = true;
if (loadData) 
{    
     ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass();    
     childClass.LoadData(this.Datatable);    
}
```

In the child Class `LoadData()` method I want to be able to set the `CurrentRow` variable of the parent and call the `MyMethod()` function.

How do I do this?

Comment: if you are trying to communicate your data with your form/window etc (as you are loading some data and updating your progress bar) i strongly recommend you to follow some MVC or MVVM approach

Comment: `MyMethod` is private. You can't call it from `ChildClass`.

Comment: what kind of association is between child and parent? inheritance? aggregation?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Good spot, I missed that. OP you'll need that change `private` to `protected` to allow that method to be accisble from child classes.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry I have edited it to be public

Comment: @ArsenMkrt A form calls the parent class where it updates progress bars etc, then this parent class calls the child

Comment: does parent contains the child? or child inherit from from parent? or you mean just parent form open child form?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt No Separate, the child class is used in other areas where the parent may differ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the solution.

In the parent I declare a new instance of the ChildClass() then bind the event handler in that class to the local method in the parent

In the child class I add a public event handler:

```
public EventHandler UpdateProgress;
```

In the parent I create a new instance of this child class then bind the local parent event to the `public` `eventhandler` in the child

```
ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
child.UpdateProgress += this.MyMethod;
child.LoadData(this.MyDataTable);
```

Then in the `LoadData()` of the child class I can call

```
private LoadData() {
    this.OnMyMethod();
}
```

Where `OnMyMethod` is:

```
public void OnMyMethod()
{
     // has the event handler been assigned?
     if (this.UpdateProgress!= null)
     {
         // raise the event
         this.UpdateProgress(this, new EventArgs());
     }
}
```

This runs the event in the parent class

Comment: Depend on your intention, using Action delegate could potentially better than EventHandler. For one reason, you don't have to worry about removing the event assignment, ie: child.UpdateProgress -= this.MyMethod;

Answer (score 85):

To access properties and methods of a parent class use the `base` keyword. So in your child class `LoadData()` method you would do this:

```
public class Child : Parent 
{
    public void LoadData() 
    {
        base.MyMethod(); // call method of parent class
        base.CurrentRow = 1; // set property of parent class
        // other stuff...
    }
}
```

Note that you would also have to change the access modifier of your parent `MyMethod()` to at least `protected` for the child class to access it.

Comment: From OP: `In the parent I create a new instance of ChildClass` - this to me implies composition, not inheritance.

Comment: I think you could be right. I'll leave this here in case it's of some use though.

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for, even though it wasn't his question :). Question title is confusing...

Comment: `In the parent I create a new instance of ChildClass` - this to me implies potential recursion. I like it. Turtles all the way down.

Comment: I agree with Emyr. This codes causes a StackOverflow for me.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott well then the issue is as Emyr stated - you're creating recursion by creating a child class inside the parent. Don't do that.

Comment: public or protected function in parent class can be called from child class without base keyword then why u use base keyword to call parent class function from child class.........reason not clear.

Comment: @Mou Some coding standards enforce its use, even though not strictly necessary. I added it here for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 5):

To follow up on the comment by suhendri to Rory McCrossan answer.  Here is an Action delegate example:

In child add:

```
public Action UpdateProgress;  // In place of event handler declaration
                               // declare an Action delegate
.
.
.
private LoadData() {
    this.UpdateProgress();    // call to Action delegate - MyMethod in
                              // parent
}
```

In parent add:

```
// The 3 lines in the parent becomes:
ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
child.UpdateProgress = this.MyMethod;  // assigns MyMethod to child delegate
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to pass the instance of `ParentClass` to the `ChildClass` on construction

```
public ChildClass
{
    private ParentClass parent;

    public ChildClass(ParentClass parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void LoadData(DateTable dt)
    {
       // do something
       parent.CurrentRow++; // or whatever.
       parent.UpdateProgressBar(); // Call the method
    }
}
```

Make sure to pass the reference to `this` when constructing `ChildClass` inside parent:

```
if(loadData){

     ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass(this); // here

     childClass.LoadData(this.Datatable);

}
```

Caveat: This is probably **not** the best way to organise your classes, but it directly answers your question.

**EDIT**: In the comments you mention that more than 1 parent class wants to use `ChildClass`. This is possible with the introduction of an interface, eg:

```
public interface IParentClass
{
    void UpdateProgressBar();
    int CurrentRow{get; set;}
}
```

Now, make sure to implement that interface on both (all?) Parent Classes and change child class to this:

```
public ChildClass
{
    private IParentClass parent;

    public ChildClass(IParentClass parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void LoadData(DateTable dt)
    {
       // do something
       parent.CurrentRow++; // or whatever.
       parent.UpdateProgressBar(); // Call the method
    }
}
```

Now anything that implements `IParentClass` can construct an instance of `ChildClass` and pass `this` to its constructor.

Comment: @CR41G14 - what exactly do you mean by "dynamic"? keyword `dynamic` or "any class not just `ParentClass`"?

Comment: Do I have to pass a constructor? Can I just "detect" the parent class that called this? AS I may want parentClass2 to call this class. Sorry if I am not making sense but it is an inherited project

Comment: @CR41G14 - No, it has to be `ParentClass` or anything that inherits it. If 2 classes both need to construct a `ChildClass` then you can make childclass take an Interface in the constructor. I'll update the answer with some detail.