# methoddecorator.fody is it possible to invoke a instance method with method OnExit

Tags: c#, aop

I'm working on a AOP project ,which there is a class (call it **classA**) inherited from an other class (call is **ParentClass**) . Code like bellow

```
[Interceptor]
class ParentClass
{
    protected void Init()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

```
class classA : ParentClass
{

}
```

When creating a new instance of classA , i want a call of ParentClass's Init() by AOP , but i find it's hard for me .
Please Help.

**update.**

Hi,guys. There is one thing you should know, i want an  AOP interception , not a method call from child class. because i have too many objects and i want a immediately call within **onExit** of a **.ctor** .

Comment: Which  AOP framework are you using?

Comment: useful i like this code only refer the code link:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743609/call-parent-method-from-child-class-c-sharp/13743643#13743643

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich , AOP framework is MethodDecorator.fody

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyParentClass
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod()
    {
    /* do parent class stuff here */
    }
}

public class MyChildClass : MyParentClass
{
   public override void SomeMethod()
   {
    /* do child class stuff here */
    base.SomeMethod(); // <--- This will call the parent class method
   }
}
```

Using Parent class any method describe then used `virtual`
Using child class any method describe then used `override`

Comment: This a direct parent method call, not AOP